# Excessive overhead (downloads) of Admin SDK of Firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using the Admin SDK of Firebase realtime database, it establishes a connection web socket connection over HTTPS to the server, which includes about 4Kb ~ 5Kb of overhead (downloads), no matter how small the set or updated data (storage).  And every device establishes a new connection after a few minutes.

My app will set or update data frequently so I am assuming Admin SDK may not be a good choice. Is there any way to reduce the download size or make these distinct user connections stay more on the server rather than for a few minutes?

Note: I also checked the Rest API after the post above, similarly it does cost 4Kb ~ 5Kb of overhead at each connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This overhead mostly comes (about 3½KB) from the SSL/TLS handshake that is needed to establish a secure connection. Since Firebase can only be accessed over a secure connection, there is no way to avoid this overhead. The best you can do is keep the connection open longer to minimize the number of times you need to reestablish the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Any idea how to keep the connection open longer?

Comment: The connection stays open while there's an active listener or while it's actively used.